# ¿Como remover un div sin afectar un div igual jquery?

Tags: jquery, html5

Al momento de hacer `click` en un boton agregar en `jquery` este genera un `append` con `4 inputs` y dos botones, un boton elimina la fila el cual funciona bien, pero hay otro `boton` que debe de borrarse junto con un `input` al momento de hacerle `click`, el problema esta en que este borra el `div` que necesito pero en todas.

**CODIGO**

```
$('.agregarDireccion').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#direcciones').append(`
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccion[]" placeholder="Dirección Alternativa">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pais_dir[]" id="pais-dir" placeholder="Pais Actual"> 
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="concat-dpto">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control dpto-dir" name="dpto_dir[]" placeholder="Departamento">       
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-dpto-dir" style="border-radius= 50px 50px;">X</button> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ciu_dir[]" placeholder="Ciudad">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove">Eliminar</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>`);
  });

//Este es el que borrar el div que necesito, pero se lo borrar a todos los que cree  
$('#direcciones').on("click",".remove-dpto-dir",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.concat-dpto').remove();
  });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir el código aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas especificar el contexto usando `this` asi:

```
$('#direcciones').on("click",".remove-dpto-dir",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('.concat-dpto').remove();
});
```

Comment: Pff men, es excelente, muchas gracias por tu interes y tu colaboración.